# ESP8266 is not getting connected to my deployed websocket on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, arduino, esp8266

I have deployed a nodejs websocket on heroku. But my ESP8266 cannot get connected to that websocket. Before deploying that websocket on heroku, i tried it out locally and it worked pretty well. ESP8266 also got connected to it without any error. Then I made some changes in nodejs socket (before deploying) in order to run it on heroku. i just don't understand what's wrong with this esp8266 code

**ESP8266's Code**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h>
boolean handshakeFailed = 0;
String data = "";
char path[] = "/"; //identifier of this device
const char *ssid = ""; //<-------------------this was entered correctly. Wifi connection was successful. websocket connection got failed
const char *password = ""; // <-------------------this was entered correctly. Wifi connection was successful. websocket connection got failed
char *host = "example.herokuapp.com"; //replace this ip address with the ip address of your Node.Js server
const int espport = 3000;

WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long interval = 300; //interval for sending data to the websocket server in ms
// Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
WiFiClient client;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  delay(1000);

  wsconnect();
  //  wifi_set_sleep_type(LIGHT_SLEEP_T);
}
void loop()
{
  if (client.connected())
  {
    currentMillis = millis();
    webSocketClient.getData(data);
    if (data.length() > 0)
    {
      Serial.println(data);
      //*************send log data to server in certain interval************************************
      //currentMillis=millis();
      if (abs(currentMillis - previousMillis) >= interval)
      {
        previousMillis = currentMillis;
        data = (String)analogRead(A0); //read adc values, this will give random value, since no sensor is connected.
        //For this project we are pretending that these random values are sensor values
        webSocketClient.sendData(data); //send sensor data to websocket server
      }
    }
    else
    {
    }
    delay(5);
  }
}

void wsconnect()
{
  // Connect to the websocket server
  if (client.connect(host, espport))
  {
    Serial.println("WebSocket Connected");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
    delay(1000);

    if (handshakeFailed)
    {
      handshakeFailed = 0;
      ESP.restart();
    }
    handshakeFailed = 1;
  }
  // Handshake with the server
  webSocketClient.path = path;
  webSocketClient.host = host;
  if (webSocketClient.handshake(client))
  {
    Serial.println("Handshake successful");
  }
  else
  {

    Serial.println("Handshake failed.");
    delay(4000);

    if (handshakeFailed)
    {
      handshakeFailed = 0;
      ESP.restart();
    }
    handshakeFailed = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: https ? doesn't the server require secure connection?

Comment: @Juraj You mean defining the host like this right? ```https://example.herokuapp.com``` ?? I tried it out. but it didn't work

Comment: you would have to use WiFiClientSecure

Comment: @SankhaRathnayake, Did you find a solution for this?